# Proof of the isomorphism $[X, \mathbb{R} P^\infty] \cong H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I want to prove the following:

> $[X, \mathbb{R} P^\infty] \cong H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ via the map $[f] \mapsto f^* w_1(\gamma^1)$ where $\gamma^1$ denotes the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{R} P^\infty$.

This is my attempt so far:

We have that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R} P^\infty) = \mathbb{Z}/2$, and that the universal cover of $\mathbb{R} P^\infty$ is $S^\infty$, which is contractible. Now consider a map $f : X \to \mathbb{R} P^\infty$ and the induced map
$$ \overline{f} : H_1(X) = \pi_1(X)/[\pi_1(X), \pi_1(X)] \to \pi_1(\mathbb{R} P^\infty). $$
We see that $\overline{f} \in Hom (H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}/2) \cong H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2)$. 
Note that $\overline{f} = 0$ exactly when $f$ lifts to $S^\infty$. But $f$ lifts to $S^\infty$ if and only if the induced map $f : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{R} P^\infty) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the contractible map. Therefore the map $[X, \mathbb{R} P^\infty] \to H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is injective.

Is this correct? And how do I go about proving surjectivity?

After poking around for a little bit I realize that this is a special case of a very general theorem about classifying spaces and Eilenberg–MacLane spaces, but that's beyond what I've learned about on the topic so I'm hoping for a more basic proof.

Comment: A priori, $[X, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}]$ does not have a group structure. In your argument so far, you are implicity using the fact that $[X, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}]$ is a group when you deduce that $[X, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}] \to H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is injective from the statement that $\overline{f} = 0$ implies $f$ is null homotopic.